# Error al activar LTV TimeStamp iTextSharp c#

Tags: c#, pdf, firma-digital

Actualmente estoy programando un firmador digital en **`C#`** con la librería de `iTextSharp`. Inicialmente el firmador hacía la tarea de forma correcta, ya que firmaba el documento, solicitaba el pin, etc. Todo lo hacía bien, hasta que me solicitaron que firmara y además activara **LTV**, que en este caso usa [PAdES](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PAdES).

El documento a firmar es un PDF, que debe de llevar una marca de un **TSA**, en una instancia lo que hago es `ITSAClient t = new TSAClientBouncyCastle("miURL");`

Hasta aquí las cosas iban bien.
Pero cuando trato de agregar el LTV de la siguiente forma

```cs
MakeSignature.SignDetached(signatureAppearance, externalSignature, chain, null, null, t, 0, CryptoStandard.CADES);
LtvVerification v = pdfStamper.LtvVerification;

LtvTimestamp.Timestamp(signatureAppearance, t, null);
```

Y me manda un mensaje que dice

> Document already pre closed

¿Podrían ayudarme por favor?

Adjunto el código:

```
public void firmarDocumentoDosTres(X509Certificate2 cert, String src, String dest, Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate[] chain2, CryptoStandard subfilter, ITSAClient tsa)

    {
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
        FileStream os = new FileStream(dest, FileMode.Create);
        PdfStamper stamper = PdfStamper.CreateSignature(reader, os, '\0',null, true);

        PdfSignatureAppearance appearance = stamper.SignatureAppearance;
        appearance.SetVisibleSignature(new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(10, 20, 100, 200), 1, "sig");

        string strTSA = System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["rutaTSA"];

        ITSAClient t = new TSAClientBouncyCastle(strTSA);
        ICrlClient crlClient = new CrlClientOnline(chain2);
        IOcspClient ocspClient = new OcspClientBouncyCastle();
        iTextSharp.text.pdf.security.IExternalSignature signature = new X509Certificate2Signature(cert, "SHA-256");

        MakeSignature.SignDetached(appearance, signature, chain2, null, null, tsa, 0, subfilter);

        stamper.Close();

        LTVSolicitudaddLtvY(dest, dest + ".sig.pdf", ocspClient, crlClient, t);
    }
```

y la llamada al agregado de LTV

```
public void LTVSolicitudaddLtvY(String src, String dest, IOcspClient ocsp, ICrlClient crl, ITSAClient tsa) 
    {

        PdfReader r = new PdfReader(src);
        FileStream fos = new FileStream(dest, FileMode.Create);

        PdfStamper stp = PdfStamper.CreateSignature(r, fos, '\0', null, true);


        LtvVerification v = stp.LtvVerification;
        AcroFields fields = stp.AcroFields;
        List<String> names = fields.GetSignatureNames();
        String sigName = names[names.Count - 1];
        PdfPKCS7 pkcs7 = fields.VerifySignature(sigName);
        if (pkcs7.IsTsp)
        {
            v.AddVerification(sigName, ocsp, crl,
                LtvVerification.CertificateOption.SIGNING_CERTIFICATE,
                LtvVerification.Level.OCSP_CRL,
                LtvVerification.CertificateInclusion.NO);
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (String name in names) 
            {
                v.AddVerification(name, ocsp, crl,
                    LtvVerification.CertificateOption.WHOLE_CHAIN,
                    LtvVerification.Level.OCSP_CRL,
                    LtvVerification.CertificateInclusion.NO);
            }
        }
        PdfSignatureAppearance sap = stp.SignatureAppearance;
        LtvTimestamp.Timestamp(sap, tsa, null);
    }
```

Este código lo que hace es activar el **LTV**, sin embargo lo que hace es agregar una nueva firma, y lo que requiere es activar el **LTV** a la existente.

Comment: Considera agregar todo el bloque del código para tener una noción más general de lo que quieras lograr, además de usar los try/catch con el respectivo Exception (Si maneja excepciones específicas) que sean más legibles.

Answer (score 1):

Tu código esta creando una nueva firma digital, porque para eso es para lo que fue diseñado:

```
 PdfStamper stp = PdfStamper.CreateSignature(r, fos, '\0', null, true);
```

Si lo que querías hacer era añadir LTV (Long Term Validation/Validación a largo plazo) a una firma existente, lo que tienes que hacer es recorrer las firmas ya presentes en el archivo PDF de entrada.

Este post de SO en inglés tiene ejemplos de como hacer lo que quieres:

[¿Cómo añadir LTV a un timestamp de una firma digital? (en un PDF usando iText)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27892960/501196)